# Why am I having WiFi troubles?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have spent literally the entire day trying to figure out why the WiFi was failing. At first it was just one laptop which had trouble connecting, staying connected etc.

Eventually it led me to renaming the WiFi, giving it a new password, making all devices forget the old one, effectively starting fresh. Now it connects, but while the devices stay connected the wifi is ridiculously slow regardless of the time of day and proximity to the router, and internet access constantly drops out. Wired connections work as well as they possibly can, but the WiFi is so slow.

So I suspected the WiFi has something wrong with it to make all the devices slow, BUT, it's only slow on two of the 3 laptops, the fasted being the only one with an Ethernet port. I ran a speed test and on the 2 slow laptops, one started the test but couldn't finish and the other couldn't even start. The one that I have been plugging the Ethernet cable into runs anywhere from 10/15mbps which is pretty much normal for my place.

Keep in mind all speed tests were done using WiFi only. The only other thing I could think to do was change the channel, and make sure i wasn't using the same one as anyone around me to avoid interference and congestion, but it did nothing.

So my question is, why on two laptops is the WiFi so bad, and why across all devices does it drop out, lose internet and run slow? I have reset all network adaptors on all devices, flushed the DNS in command prompt, tried disabling all antivirus and changed the WiFi channel to no avail. I'm at my wits end here and I would really appreciate some help.

Best performing laptop is a HP, the other two are lenovo. I'm trying to connect to a netgear and before you say it, no I cant try connecting straight to the modem because I have a router/modem combo.

Comment: 1) Congested channel? 2) Interference? 3) Bad router? 4) Weak / slow wifi receivers?

Comment: Also btw changing to any channel besides 1, 6, or 11 is a bit of a myth. Channels overlap and since those three are the most commonly used, the ones in the middle end up just seeing surrounding 1,6,11 traffic as side band noise. And your router cooperates with the people around you on the same channel to negotiate congestion. But if youre in between the most popular channels and so most of the traffic around you is noise, that can't happen, the noise just degrades the signal, and the problem often gets worse. So stick to whichever of 1,6,11 has the least people on it. Talking about 2.4ghz.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to start checking the stats in your router. Find out if you can get the TX and RX rate that the devices are negotiating and the signal strength as well as the noise. If the router doesn't give this then many Wifi apps on IOS and Android will display these stats.

For instance, i'm on my router and looking at my phone's wifi stats and it says:

```
TX Rate  RX Rate Info    Signal  Noise  SNR  
72M      24M     HT20PS  -40     -89    48
```

For signal strength (dBm) the range is something like -20dBm (strong) to -99dBm (weak). You want noise to be weak. SNR is the ratio of the previous numbers and Wifi needs an SNR of at least ~10 to get things going and the larger the SNR the greater the speeds you'll get.

Things to check:

- make sure your antennas in back of the router are well screwed-in and aren't surrounded by metallic structures and many layers of walls that may mess with the signal.
- note that a crappy microwave oven can kill the wifi signal since it will effectively swamp the channels with noise.

Things to try:

- if you know how to tether your laptop to your cell phone then try that and see if you determine if your router is the problem (assuming you have a reasonable data plan on the phone)

Good luck.